# How to add custom ticker/label with custom text in outlook email compose window just below subject text box?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I want to add custom text in label which will be information to the user who opens email compose window.

I have tried using form regions, but it do not allow adding new forms in IPM.Note at any location. I think there are only 4 ways to add form regions like adjoining, replace, replace all and separate. 
Is there any other way using which I can add this label/message below the subject? I know we can do it using add-in express but I do not want to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the adjoining layout doesn't allow placing a form region on top of the window. The best what you can do is to create an adjucent Outlook window, see [Creating Adjacent Windows In Outlook](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/OlAdjacentWindows/) for more information.

And yes, an alternative way is to use Add-in Express which supports the required layout - `TopSubpane`.